# Insert Characters into table cells onkeyup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, onkeyup

I want to insert characters from the *html input* into **table cells** as users types them using **jQuery**.  The Image below illustrates what I need to achieve:

[image]

That if as user keys in for example name **TABLE**, in replaces the stars in the first column.

This what I have tried to do:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>


<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#inputv").keyup(function(){
  var ttt = $("#inputv").val();
 
  $("#test").html(ttt);
    
});
});

</script>
<style>
td {
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;}

</style>
<input type="text" id="inputv">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="test">*</td>
    <td  id="test">*</td>
    <td  id="test">*</td>
    <td  id="test">*</td>
    <td  id="test">*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is that it's inserting the whole word *eg TABLE* in the first cell *instead insert each character in it's own cell*

*Anyone with an idea how to solve this kindly assist*

Comment: so what is the error here

Comment: which image there is no image

Comment: The error is that it's inserting the whole word eg TABLE in the first cell instead insert each character in it's own cell

Comment: @Bhargav kidly run the code to see

Comment: but whene input is `table 1` then which cell get value there is only 5 cell

Comment: `id ` is a unique identity of element so you can not assign same id for all

Comment: @Bhargav that's the problem I'm facing. I want each character to occupy a space in the cell as marked by the '*'. I thought that approach(same id to all cells)will work but it isn't. Do you have a better approach?

Comment: you did not enough explanation for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for what you want exactly.
and must use the class instead of id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputv").keyup(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var id = $("#inputv").val();
    $("td.test").each(function() {
     if(i <= $("#inputv").val().length)
     {
         $(this).html(id[i]);
     }


      i++;
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @addy. Works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

There you use id for each of the td in table I suggest you use a class instead of the id for multiple same elements because id used for an individual element in HTML.If you want to add value in all td on the same time you can use following code.
**There am change your `test` id to `test` class.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#inputv").keyup(function(){

     $("td.test").each(function(){
            $(this).html($("#inputv").val());
   });

});
});
```

else for an individual column, you can use the following:
**there I assign a `test` id to your td.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#inputv").keyup(function(){

   $("#test").html($("#inputv").val());
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you @addy. I see you have understand my issue.  But now In have another issue with your approach. When I type name _12345_.. It is repeated in all cells. But what I want is when I type **12345**  `1 to be on 1st cell, 2 on second, 3 on third, ...5 to be on 5th.`

Comment: is there only max 5 chars in your input text.

Comment: Yes. For now I want to use 5.. so that they fit in the 5 spaces provided in the table cells

Answer (score 1):

try this code i thing its helpful

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputv").keyup(function() {

    $("td.test").each(function() {
      $(this).html($("#inputv").val());
    });

  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="inputv">
  <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="test">*</td>
      <td class="test">*</td>
      <td class="test">*</td>
      <td class="test">*</td>
      <td class="test">*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bhargav. But there is little issue on that. When I type `12345`,It is repeated in all cells. But what I want is when I type **12345** `1 to be on 1st cell, 2 on second, 3 on third, ...5 to be on 5th.`

Comment: on what about 8 and *

Comment: there is no 8 and *

Comment: but think its happen user input 12345678 than what

Comment: I want to use 5 chars ie12345.. so that they fit in the 5 spaces provided in the table cells.. `kindly ignore 12345678`.  I want it to work with 5 chars for now.

Comment: but no any restriction on input

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. i think this is what you want. hope it helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputv").keypress(function(e) {
    $('td').eq($("#inputv").val().length).html(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputv">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="test">*</td>
    <td class="test">*</td>
    <td class="test">*</td>
    <td class="test">*</td>
    <td class="test">*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```